# MS SQL Server DB much larger than sum of table sizes

Tags: sql-server, database

I've been testing a DB-migration tool, which inserts data into all my DB tables from another RDBMS.

On each run, the Migration tool deletes * from the target tables.

I also run 'Shrink' on the SQL Server db on a regular basis

Despite this, my DB has now grown in size to be orders of magnitude larger than the sum of the sizes of each table.  The well-known query for determining table sizes as follows:

```
SELECT 
   sum( p.rows ) AS RowCounts,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
```

Returns:

```
RowCounts   TotalSpaceMB    UsedSpaceMB UnusedSpaceMB

2816317     161.44          154.04      7.40
```

Yet, the size of the DB on disk is 32024.13 MB

What else may be taking up space?  How can I safely free it up?

Comment: Educated guess: Full recovery model(by default) 1) Start performing transaction log backups 2) (set simple recovery model) - could be dangerous. **[Recovery Models (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)**

Comment: I've switched to 'Simple' Recovery Model, and the DB size now reports 171 DB - but the disk space has not been reclaimed - how can I do this?  I assume I can shrink the log somehow?

Comment: You have to [shrink transaction log](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/).

Answer (score 0):

Delete * is not ideal if you want to reduce the size.  Try to truncate the tables and then insert. Also, which tool are you using?  I would recommend DMA or SSMA.